# How to calculate MTD in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a calendar table with the following fields, How to calculate MTD/YTD using the below fields in redshift. How can I create MTD/YTD fields?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MTD/YTD in the context of aggregations are used to aggregate data/metrics from the beginning for the month to today for MTD and beginning of the year to today in for YTD. This table alone does not meet that criteria.

Ref - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year-to-date